# Lights blink when toggling ceiling fan in another room

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan with light in room A. I have recessed lights in room B.

I noticed that if I have the ceiling fan set as Fan-On and Light-Off, and I switch the fan's wall switch (fan and light is the same switch) to on or off, the recessed LED lights in room B will blink once.

Room B's lights do not blink if I have both fan and light set as on or fan is set to off.

Is this a wiring problem? Or is that some special electrical behavior involving a motor? Could this cause problem with device sharing the same circuit?

Comment: Are they on the same circuit breaker?

Comment: Do they blink or just dim slightly?  Are they incandescent or LED?  When did this start (or is this a new place for you)?

Comment: Yes, they are controlled by the same circuit breaker. The lights in room B are Off. I only  noticed it recently because I rarely use the Fan-On/Light-Off configuration.

Comment: Are the lights in Room B incandescent bulbs, CFLs, or LEDs?

Comment: LED. Will update question.

Comment: What make and model are the LED fixtures in Room B?

Comment: Providing make/model of as many devices as possible (fan, switches, recessed lights) will help. Also, "ceiling fan _set_ on" - does that simply mean that the fan is turned on, or is there some sort of smart switch/software control involved?

Comment: Generic recessed ceiling LED light. Generic ceiling fan with light/fan controlled by pull strings. Not fancy stuffs.